# Teradata UPDATE column using length of values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-update, teradata, calculated-columns, string-length

I have successfully selected the length of each record in a column using the following code:

```
SELECT Length(Table.Town) as LengthOfTown 
FROM Table;
```

I now want to update a column called TownLength in my table with these values, and have not been able to do it, I have been trying the following code:

```
UPDATE Table
SET TownLength = Length(Town)
```

This seems to run ok but returns a blank column.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: You may need to run `commit` after you run the `update`.

Comment: HELP SESSION will display your session defaults including the transaction semantics of TERADATA or ANSI. As Gordon mentioned, you will need to run `commit` after the update if your transactions semantics are ANSI.

Comment: Thanks, my transaction semantics were Teradata. Apologies but I had the TownLength column set as VARCHAR - when I changed this to INT my query worked. Thanks for your help, sorry for wasting your time :)

Comment: Do you think I should delete my question to avoid confusing anyone?

Comment: When you update a VARCHAR with an INTEGER you get an automatic typecase which results in a right aligned string like `'       12'`, which is silently truncated when it's assigned to `TownLength`. This will work `SET TownLength = TRIM(Char_Length(Town))`, but a numeric target is better, of course.

Comment: Thanks dnoeth - I had dropped the VCHAR column and then added a new INTEGER column, so I think it is ok.